# Set-AzApiManagementPolicy - How to set policy on multiple Operations

Tags: azure, powershell, api, apim

I am trying to understand how to apply custom policies (ie. Caching) to target each operations within an given API.  Below is a sample cache policy file (xml) for a "Get Test1" policy:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="false" must-revalidate="false" downstream-caching-type="none" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
    <cache-store duration="3600" />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

So based on the above, I have several other operations within the same API that I want to apply unique policy to (Get Test2, Get Test3...).  My understanding is that I need to execute a new Set-AzApiManagementPolicy for each operation I want to apply a policy to.  Is this correct?  This seem a bit tedious.

Can Set-AzApiManagementPolicy take a single XML file with various scopes defined within it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set policies at an API level to ensure it is applied for all operations within an API. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-9.6.0#example-3-set-api-scope-policy) is the example in the reference doc for the PowerShell cmdlet.

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "Api-Default-WestUS" -ServiceName "contoso"
Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId "9876543210" -Policy $PolicyString
```

Ensure the [`base`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies?tabs=form#use-base-element-to-set-policy-evaluation-order) element is set appropriately for your use case.